# Where can I find the current CIRCULATING SUPPLY?

Tags: circulating-supply

After [TZScan](https://tzscan.io/) is closed, I can't use old API the check the CIRCULATING SUPPLY. Then I Got the new block explorer([TZStats](https://tzstats.com/)) in [HERE](https://medium.com/tezoscommons/a-guide-to-tezos-block-explorers-5c4addb8110e). But I found the number of CS and TS in [CMC](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/tezos/) is totally different. Which one is CURRENT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tzstats has a rather detailed breakdown

https://api.tzstats.com/explorer/tip

Their definition of "circulating supply" is total tokens - unclaimed - frozen (in baking deposits) - TF's tokens that are still unvested, which is a reasonable definition.

I'm not sure what CMC uses but they're likely not very current and likely less rigorous.

Comment: But even CMC had been updated for a long time. The CS in CMC should not be that much more than the CS in TZStats. That is about 111.2M more! How would it happen? Buyback?

Comment: CMC likely includes unclaimed tez in the circulating supply because they could be claimed and spent at any time

Comment: WoW! You know Tezos very well. Are you the man from Official?

Comment: @JIANYunpeng you'd expect the co-founder of Tezos to know one or two things about the project ;)